# How to implement a JPanel that shows/hide content depending on its width?

Tags: java, swing, layout, miglayout

I'm trying to implement a JPanel that displays more or less information depending on the available size.

Basically, the idea is have a default content like this:

[image]

That can shrinks to this when the space is reduced:

[image]

My code is like this:

```
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

class PanelDemo extends JPanel {
private final JLabel title = new JLabel();

private final JLabel counter1 = new JLabel("00");
private final JLabel counter1Label = new JLabel();

private final JLabel counter2 = new JLabel("00");
private final JLabel counter2Label = new JLabel();

/**
 * Instantiates a new obs app cadre message bloc panel.
 */
public PanelDemo() {
    this.setOpaque(false);
    initGUI();
}

private final void initGUI() {
    // 1°)
    final MigLayout migLayout = new MigLayout(
            "fillx, hidemode 2, debug",
            "[growprio 0][]" //define 4 columns
    );

    setLayout(migLayout);

    // 2°)
    //
    add(title, "spanx");
    add(counter1, "newline");
    add(counter1Label);
    add(counter2);
    add(counter2Label);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("test 4");
    jFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("fillx, debug"));
    final PanelDemo item1 = new PanelDemo();
    item1.title.setText("Element 1");
    item1.counter1Label.setText("First lbl");
    item1.counter2Label.setText("Second lbl");
    jFrame.getContentPane().add(item1, "growx, gpx 110");


    final PanelDemo item2 = new PanelDemo();
    item2.title.setText("Element 2");
    item2.counter1Label.setText("First lbl");
    item2.counter2Label.setText("Second lbl");
    jFrame.getContentPane().add(item2, "growx, gpx 100");

    jFrame.pack();
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
} }
```

I tried to add a ComponentListener and override componentResized() to find when I could show/hide my secondary labels but I was not successful.

Does anybody know how to implement such a behaviour that goes well with MigLayout grow priorities?

**Update1:** I was thinking... what if I set the minimum width to counter1+label1, and the maximum size to counter2+label2 and then listen to resize operations and change the preferred size to either its minimum or its maximum. Would that mecanism work?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public static JPanel panel(String name) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 0, wrap 4, fillx, debug", "[][][shrink 200][shrink 200, grow 200]"));
    panel.add(new JLabel(name), "spanx 4");
    panel.add(new JLabel("00"));
    panel.add(new JLabel("First lbl"));
    panel.add(new JLabel("01"));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Second lbl"));
    return panel;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 10, gap 10, fillx, debug"));
    panel.add(panel("Element 1"), "w (50% - 15)!");
    panel.add(panel("Element 2"), "w (50% - 15)!");

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I had trouble getting the two main columns to resize equally; I had to do it by setting a width on the components rather than the columns. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: The behaviour is not exactly the one expect. I should have been clearer. When the space available for the second labels (2nd counter + 2nd description) is no longer available, I want the whole component to change its state by removing/setVisible(false) the secondary labels and having its preferred size reduced to reflect the new layout. Later on, when the parent container has more space available, my panel should return to its initial full state. Does my idea make sens?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented an autohide mechanism with a LayoutCallback switching the visibility of the component depending on the width of the panel.

Here is an example:

```
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("fill");
JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);

JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label 1");
label1.putClientProperty("autohide.width", 300);

JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Label 2");
label2.putClientProperty("autohide.width", 200);

panel.add(label1, "grow");
panel.add(label2, "grow");                

layout.addLayoutCallback(new LayoutCallback() {
    @Override
    public void correctBounds(ComponentWrapper wrapper) {
        JComponent component = (JComponent) wrapper.getComponent();

        Number width = (Number) component.getClientProperty("autohide.width");
        if (width != null) {
            if (component.isVisible() && wrapper.getParent().getWidth() < width.intValue()) {
                component.setVisible(false);
            } else if (!component.isVisible() && wrapper.getParent().getWidth() > width.intValue()) {
                component.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here the label1 is hidden when the width of the panel shrinks below 300 pixels, and label2 disappears when the width is less than 200 pixels.